# Angular, filter objects in repeat, replace with new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dynamically bringing in objects to an repeat, and when I get a certain type of object, I want to make a service call and replace it. My best guess was a filter on the repeat would be a good idea. So here is what I tried.

```
    .filter('filterByType', [
        vitModel.componentName,
        function(myVitModel) {
            return function(items) {
                var newObj = _.map(items, function(item) {
                    if (!item.data) {
                        return item;
                    } else {
                        var newModel = new myVitModel(item.data);
                        newModel.getFullVitData().then(function() {
                            return newModel.data;
                        });
                    }
                });

                return newObj;
            };
        }
    ]);
```

This seems to have some problems in the logic, but the basic idea is if an item comes in that has .data it needs to call a new myVitModel on the data and replace it.

Everything seems sound until I drop an object in that does have the .data, then I am getting a

```
 Error: $rootScope:infdig
  Infinite $digest Loop
```

So I'm not sure where in this problem is being caused, possibly looping in on itself? Could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: a filter can't return a completely different object than what was passed in; that just causes the filter to need to be re-evaluated on the next pass, which in turn causes a new object to be returned, which needs to be re-evaluated, etc... you complicate this even more by putting a promise inside the filter, which may not be handled until after the filter has returned the object, again creating a case where now the object has to be evaluated on the filter again, calling the promise again.

Comment: @Claies is correct, using this as a filter in the DOM will never work. You can however use the `$filter` service injected into either your controller or a service to work with your data before it is injected into the DOM in which case this would work. Despite that I'm guessing the method `getFullVitData` is pulling a resource from the API. This looks like it'd be better handled server side.

Comment: @Claies thank you for taking the time to explain, could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: @Claies Returning a new object is the whole point of a filter.